# Preventing selected text in ckeditor 4.3 from getting deleted

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to make a plugin for CK Editor 4.3 which will prevent the selected text from getting deleted by any user. I have enclosed the selected text in span tag and set its contentEditable attribute to false and disabling all keys if the selected text is on an uneditable span tag , it works for IE 8 , but not for IE 10. The code is as shown below

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('disableelement',
{
    init: function(editor)
    {
        editor.addCommand('insertDisableelement',
        {
            exec : function( editor )
            {    
                var mySelection = editor.getSelection();
                var selectedText = null;

                if (CKEDITOR.env.ie) 
                {
                    selectedText = mySelection.getNative().createRange().text + " ";
                } 
                else 
                {
                    selectedText = mySelection.getNative();
                }

                var e = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('span');

                e.setStyle('background-color', '#81F7F3');

                e.setAttributes({
                    contentEditable :'false'    
                });

                e.setText(selectedText);
                editor.insertElement(e);
                editor.insertHtml("");
            }
        }); // end of addCommand

        editor.ui.addButton('Disableelement',
        {
            label: 'Disable element',
            command: 'insertDisableelement',
            icon: this.path + 'images/disable1.png'
        });

        CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(editorEvent) 
        {
            editorEvent.editor.on('key', function(keyEvent) 
            {
                var node = keyEvent.editor.getSelection().getStartElement();

                if (node.getAttribute('contentEditable') == 'false') 
                {
                    alert("key event=" + keyEvent);
                    keyEvent.cancel();
                }
            });
        }); // end of instanceReady
    } // end of init
}); // end of plugins.add
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: [Widgets](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets) are what you're looking for (+[blog post](http://ckeditor.com/blog/Widget-Tutorials-and-SDK-Published)).

Comment: I'm curious to the exact situation is? I can't imagine a situation like this where the undeletable element would still be contained within the editable text and could not be contained outside and injected later on. Sounds very difficult even with a widget.

Comment: Oh and btw, that `instaceReady` being inside a plugin `init` function is a little odd, it might be better in the same scope as `plugins.add`. You have an interesting coding style as well, it's rare to see a style like that for JS :).

Comment: What the user expects is very tricky, indeed. But a CKEditor Widget that has no editable area and all keyboard events blocked might do the job, more or less. Still, there are other concerns like clipboard support, i.e. cutting the widget out (possible to overcome, I guess). But what worries me a lot is operating on large selections (i.e. "select all" + "delete", "select all" and "paste" etc.). This might be very weird. To be honest, I'd search for solution outside CKEditor, perhaps refining some logic would simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put it in a widget and not put it as an editable field?